# Backing up a RIAK database data

Tags: backup, riak

I'm very new to RIAK. I have a cluster with 5 nodes and I want to backup the data on the cluster. I ran the following command to backup data.

```
[root@PCPRIAK33 local]# riak-admin backup localhost riak /var/local/temp all
```

However I am getting the following error.

```
Attempting to restart script through sudo -H -u riak
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{nocatch,{could_not_reach_node,localhost}},[{riak_kv_backup,ensure_connected,1,[{file,"src/riak_kv_backup.erl"},{line,171}]},{riak_kv_backup,backup,3,[{file,"src/riak_kv_backup.erl"},{line,40}]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,572}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Can you please help me out? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer your immediate question (how to use `riak-admin backup`) first, but see the comments on preferred methods of backing up, at the end.

The command is:

`riak-admin backup <node name> <erlang cookie> <file name with path> all`

The node name you can find in your riak `vm.args` file (look for the line that looks like `-name riak@127.0.0.1`). It'll be of the form `riak@xx.xx.xx.xx` with the IP address. So, on my local machine, a single node is named `riak@127.0.0.1`.

The erlang cookie is also found in the `vm.args` file, it will most likely be `erlang`.

The file name parameter should be a fully-qualified path to the actual file name (meaning, you can't give it just a directory name). The filename and extension are arbitrary. So, I would use something like `cluster_backup.riak`. 
So, to put it all together, your [backup command](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/tools/riak-admin/#backup) should look like:

`riak-admin backup riak@<your node ip> riak /var/local/temp/cluster_backup.riak all`

Now, having said all that, I don't recommend using the `riak-admin backup` and `restore` commands to back up your whole cluster. For several reasons. One, it stores every replica of every object. Meaning, if you're running with the default replica value of `n=3`, you will be storing 3 copies of each object in your backup file.
Two, the code invoked by that command is single-threaded, and not connection pooled. So all in all, it's going to be SLOW to restore and backup.

Instead, I recommend one of the following approaches:

1. Take filesystem level snapshots of the data directories of each node. This is the approach currently recommended by Basho, and detailed here: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/backups/
2. If you definitely want a "logical" backup (meaning, an export of the objects contained in the cluster), you can use an experimental standalone tool such as the [Riak Data Migrator](https://github.com/basho/riak-data-migrator) (but see the limitations in the Readme).

I recommend testing out / timing each of these approaches, to see which one is faster for your situation.